# PHP SoapClient SoapParam sub variable?

Tags: php, soap-client

i have a question about one my PHP SoapClient request...

how to make sub params? I give example for more information

This is my xml:
...

```
<ns1:GetPackInfo>
 <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">xxx</UserName>
 <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">xxx</Password>
 <PackInfo xsi:type="ns2:TPackInfo"/>
```

...

I need to put sub parameters in PackInfo- example :

```
<ns1:GetPackInfo>
 <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">xxx</UserName>
 <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">xxx</Password>
 <PackInfo xsi:type="ns2:TPackInfo">
  <PackCode xsi:type="xsd:string">60000</PackCode>
 </PackInfo>
```

How to do it?

I use :

```
    class Soap extends SoapClient
{
    const url = 'https://..../wsdl/... example';


    function __construct()
    {
     $url = self::url;

     parent::__construct($url, array(
         'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
         'encoding' => 'utf-8',
         'trace' => true,
         'connection_timeout' => 900,
             'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
     ));
    }
...
     try
     {
//service requirements
            $user = new SoapParam('xxx', "UserName");
            $pass = new SoapParam('xxx', "Password");

         $result = $this->$method_name($user, $pass, $params);
```